# Alternative date command option in AIX

Tags: unix-timestamp, aix

I want to convert specific date to timestamp in AIX. Following command is working in GNU/LINUX flavor.
Can someone please help me to get it done in AIX as well?

Command working on GNU/LINUX:

Command -> `date -d"Nov 14 02:31" "+%s"`

Output -> `1542162660`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this with Perl, if you have `POSIX::strptime`
Example program (totimestamp.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use POSIX ("tzset", "mktime");
use POSIX::strptime;

POSIX::tzset ();

my $ARGC= scalar (@ARGV);
my $tstamp;

if ($ARGC < 1) {
    $tstamp= time ();

} else {
    my $tstr= $ARGV[0];
    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst);
    ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = 
    POSIX::strptime($tstr, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");

    $tstamp= POSIX::mktime ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year);
}

printf ("%d\n", $tstamp);
```

Usage:

```
perl ./totimestamp.pl "Nov 16 14:40:00 2018"
1542375600
```